# JavaScript files are directly visible just by changing the URL

Tags: javascript, hosting, web-hosting

I have recently taken a web hosting service and I was trying to upload all my source codes into the server.Though the site is up and running now, I am stuck with a problem, all my resources have become a link for example: if my domain name is www.example.com, the users can access my .js files just by changing the URL to www.example.com/script.js. I don't want this to happen.I have checked a couple of websites by changing their URLstheir source codes are not visible.

Should I change the structure of my resources by putting everything into folders
or is there something I should do from the code?

Comment: "By changing their URLs, their source codes are not visible". Do you have any proof of this? This is not possible, and I'm 100% certain you are checking the wrong URLs, because a script on a static host must be accessible by navigating to the URL, that's just how HTTP works.

Comment: Oops! I have realised that the name of the script files can be different.so if I know the name and path of the javascript files, can i just go to thedomin.com/<path> ?? to get the javascript files?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript source code is accessible by design. There is almost nothing you can do to hide files if you need browser to use them.

One of solutions is to obfuscate javascript so it is very hard to analyse by human.

Other involves parsers checking referer and / or creating special tokens for websites, so that whenever you hit html page it is creating token in the memory, and only using this token you are able to access javascript. But basically if you want to hide javascript from user, then you should not use javascript in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I am not doing an inspect element to look at the .js file. if I just navigate it to mydomain.com/script.js it shows me the whole javascript as plain HTML. Can I access js files of other websites in a similar way?

Comment: @LakshmanaDeepesh: Yes. Example: bbc.co.uk site has inline javascript and <script> references to other javascript files. Looking into source code shows that file http://static.bbci.co.uk/wwhp/1.114.0/modules/vendor/pre-built/vwo/mvt-snippet.js is loaded and you can view it directly in your browser.